# inheritation: using super() function in __init__ method

Tags: python

is this ok to use super() in **init** like this?

```
class Command:

    def __init__(self, command_payload: bytearray, command_type, command_identifier: int,
                        command_arguments: List[str]):
        self._command_payload = command_payload
        self._command_type = command_type
        self._command_identifier = command_identifier
        self._command_arguments = command_arguments


class ShellExecuteCommand(Command):

    def __init__(self, command_type, command_identifier: int, command_arguments: List[str], shell_command):
        super.__init__(self, command_type, command_identifier,)
        command_arguments = [shell_command]
        self._command_arguments = command_arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `super` the way it's intended but you need to actually call the built-in function by placing parentheses after it, like so:

```py
class ShellExecuteCommand(Command):

    def __init__(self, command_type, command_identifier: int, command_arguments: List[str], shell_command):
        # notice ``super().__init__``, not ``super.__init__``
        super().__init__(self, command_type, command_identifier,)  
    command_arguments = [shell_command]
    self._command_arguments = command_arguments
```

but yes it's ok to use `super` to call the superclasses' `__init__` method as you are doing here -- that's the most common use!

https://realpython.com/python-super/#what-can-super-do-for-you